# Program will read the whole .csv file into a Set and will be able to find a offending employee by time, IP address and port of internet access

Tags: java

I have the following a homework assignment:

A company firewall monitors all internet connections and logs them into a CSV file with the following format:

```
date_time;src_IP;src_port;dst_IP;dst_port;data_size;
```

Example:

```
2017-12-31/22:31:15;192.168.1.23;23899;77.75.77.53;80;289456;
2017-12-31/22:31:15;192.168.1.23;23901;77.75.77.53;80;289456;
2017-12-31/22:31:48;192.168.1.23;23902;77.75.77.53;80;2903;
```

As you can see, the `date_time` column is not unique. Only the combination of all the data in one row is unique.

You can parse the data by using `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd/HH:mm:ss")`.

Create a program, which will read the whole CSV into a Set and will be able to quickly find an offending employee by the time, IP address and/or port of the internet access.

I really can't solve it, so any help will be appreciated!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // my task:
        //ask the user for the offending IP address
        //then while reading the csv print all the lines which
        //contains the offending IP address (it could be either dest. IP address or source IP)
        // the user can also give u a date of the attack.
        //then u must print only lines with the given date.
        String Ipaddr = "192.168.1.23";
        try {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("data.csv"));
            while (s.hasNext()) {
                String line = s.nextLine();
                String items [] = line.split(";");

                System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(items));
            }


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Create a proper object `InternetConnection` (or similar) that represents (all values of) a line and store those objects in a `Set<InternetConnection>`. I recommend **not to use `SimpleDateFormat` and all related deprecated stuff** but `java.time` instead...

Comment: I don't understand how a Set will help you in finding quickly what you want. You will only benefit from loading the file into a data structure if you do this once and reuse this in-memory-structure for multiple requests.

Comment: *"I really can't solve it, so any help will be appreciated!"*  - Please explain specifically what is causing you problems.  And please also read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define and initialize a field like this:

```java
Map<Date, Set<Employee>> employees = new HashMap<>();
```

And Employee contains:

```java
class Employee {
    String sourceIp; // src_ip
    String sourcePort; // src_port
    String destinationIp; // dst_ip
    String destinationPort; // dst_port
    int dataSize; // data_size
}
```

According to your code, the part of while loop can be changed to:

```java
while (s.hasNext()) {
    String line = s.nextLine();
    String items [] = line.split(";");

    Date date = dateFormat.parse(items[0]);
    if(!employees.containsKey(date)) {
        employees.put(date, new HashSet<>());
    }
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    // Put src_ip, src_port, dst_ip ... etc into the variable 'employee'
    employees.get(date).add(employee);
}
```

- Variable `dateFormat` is equal to SimpleDateFormat.

You can get Employees values set using the field we initialized before.

```java
Set<Employee> employees = employees.get(specificDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Start top-down:

> A company firewall monitors all internet connections and logs them into a CSV file...
>
> Create a program, which will read the whole CSV into a Set and will be able to quickly find an offending employee by the time, IP address and/or port of the internet access.

This will in something like:

```
Set<LogLine> internetTraffic = readInternetTraffic("/var/logs/itraf.log", internetTraffic);
... // Data structures

List<Employee> findOffendingEmployeesByTimeIP(...);
List<Employee> findOffendingEmployeesByTimePort(...);
```

As I doubt that findBy-methods will be optimal using the entire Set only, but will profit by maps or a sorting on time and such, you might want to process the Set
during or after the reading.

Useful: a [sub map with keys in a range](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html#subMap(K,K)).

```
List<Employee> find(LocalDateTime from, LocalDateTime to, ...) {
    SortedMap<LocalDateTime, LogLine> map = new TreeMap<>();
    ...
    SortedMap<LocalDateTime, LogLine> submap = map.subMap​(from, to);
```

The exact data structure(s) to derive from `Set<LogLine>` for the retrieval method(s) you will construct *as needed*.